# Efficiently get distinct pair of values from large table with just read access

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to get the distinct a, b pair of values

`select distinct a, b from table`

from a table with 2bil+ rows. The query takes 20 minutes.

The table has anywhere between 6,000 to 20,000 entries for each distinct a, b.

We do not have write access so we cannot create indices.

Are there any solutions to make it faster?

Thanks.

Comment: No. If you can't use indexes, the query will have to scan the entire table. *Anything* you do will have to read all that data and send it somewhere else, which would still scan the entire table.

Comment: If you can replicate the data in some efficient way, you could copy it to a reporting table, perhaps in a different database, and add the appropriate indexes. A good option would be to create a columnstore index which would effectively index *and* compress the entire table. If the rows have an increasing ID and don't change for example, you could retrieve new rows by filtering using the maximum ID you cloned the last time.